# After exclude module 'answer-shim' in the android gradle for io.branch.sdk couldn't build with proguard

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, android-proguard, branch.io

When try to build the release build with proguard enable getting below warning and couldn't build the APK successfully.

```
Warning:io.branch.referral.ExtendedAnswerProvider: can't find referenced class com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.KitEvent
Warning:io.branch.referral.ExtendedAnswerProvider: can't find referenced class com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.AnswersOptionalLogger
Warning:io.branch.referral.ExtendedAnswerProvider: can't find referenced class com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.KitEventLogger
Warning:io.branch.referral.ExtendedAnswerProvider: can't find referenced class com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.AnswersOptionalLogger
Warning:io.branch.referral.ExtendedAnswerProvider: can't find referenced class com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.KitEventLogger
Warning:io.branch.referral.ExtendedAnswerProvider: can't find referenced class com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.KitEvent
Warning:there were 14 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
Error:java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.android.answers.shim.**

to the proguard file

Comment: Indeed, this is the documented answer in [Branch SDK github repo](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking#proguard-warning-or-errors-with-answers-shim-module)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude Crashlytics from Proguard you can use these 2 lines

`-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**`

Check out Fabric's [Proguard page](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html)

Comment: Despite what Fabric says, you shouldn't keep EVERYTHING in `com.crashlytics` package. That is very selfish of them =) Follow Ilanthirayan Paramanathan's suggestion and don't warn individual classes.

Comment: why do you need both lines? If you use fabric, then -keep is enough, if you don't then -dontwarn is enough. Or am I mistaken?